# How to expand a make a Row child take maximum height inside a list item?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following widget to represent one item in my `ListView`:

```
class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/100'),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Lorem'),
                      Text('Ipsum'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I get the following result:

[image]

I would like the `Column` element on the right of the image to expand vertically so that its `mainAxisAligment` actually does add some space between its 3 children.

I have tried adding a `crossAxisAlignment` of `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` on the parent Row, but then I get an exception that says "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height."

How else can I expand this Column vertically?

Comment: Works as expected in DartPad, and seems right as well.

Comment: You can place a sized box before your image tag with height = double. infinity though it seems like your solution should work but in case if not you can try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As far as I understand, you want to space between them, if that's true, you can use **IntrinsicHeight** widget.
sorry for my bad English.

```
class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/100'),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text('Lorem'),
                        Text('Ipsum'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```